# Spring JMS @JmsListener another concurrency for one method

Tags: java, jboss6.x, spring-jms

How can I change default concurrency for only one method by @JmsListener ?
I have added concurrency to @JmsListener (like below) but nothing changed in the "JBoss admin console Runtime JMS Queue Metrics".
I have JBoss 6.4, Spring JMS version 4.3.1.RELEASE.

**My listener:**

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "myJmsQueueListenerContainerFactory", destination = "some.destination", concurrency = "3-10")
@SendTo("some.place")
public TransactionBookingStatus bookTransaction(Message message) throws JMSException {
    //my implementation
}
```

**My default configuration:**

```
@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean jmsConnectionFactoryFactoryBean() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    factory.setJndiName("java:/ConnectionFactory");

    return factory;
}

public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    return (ConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactoryFactoryBean().getObject();
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate testMessageTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate tmpl = new JmsTemplate();

    tmpl.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());

    return tmpl;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myJmsQueueListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-40");

    factory.setErrorHandler(new TrnJmsErrorHandler());

    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work - turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.jms` and you'll see messages about consumer management - be sure to include the thread in the log configuration and you should see 3 consumer threads.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40908517Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40908517Application.class, args);
        JmsTemplate template = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
        }
        context.getBean(CountDownLatch.class).await();
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public CountDownLatch latch() {
        return new CountDownLatch(3);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo", concurrency = "3-40")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in + " received on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        latch().countDown();
    }

}
```

Result (3 threads as expected):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

bar received on DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3
bar received on DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2
bar received on DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1
```

Comment: I made some tests depending on your advice and unfortunately it looks like concurrency from @JmsListener didn't work. Is there another way to set concurrency for only one method ?

Comment: Define "didn't work". I just wrote a quick test app and it worked exactly as expected - see my edit.